# ML estimation for bivariate data.

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood, bivariate-distributions

Consider the random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint distribution
$$F(x,y)=[1-e^{-a_{1}x}]^{\theta}+[1-e^{-a_{2}y}]^{\theta}-[1-e^{-a_{1}x-a_{2}y}]^{\theta},$$
where $a_{1}>0$, $a_{2}>0$, $0<\theta\leq 1$ and $x, y>0$.
Clearly, when $\theta=1$, the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
I am estimating the parameters $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$ and $\theta$, using a  bivariate real data which has correlation coefficient .90. The MLE corresponding this data for $\theta$ is turns out to be around $.98000$, which implies the data nearly independent. Is this MLE for $\theta$ correct?

Comment: If one can find the way in which the population correlation depends on the parameters, that might shed some light.  If you set $a_1$, $a_2$, and $\theta$ equal to the MLEs that you got, do you know what the population correlation would be? (It's a simple function of some simple integrals, but whether they can be done in closed for is not clear to me.)  Also, a high sample correlation might not mean much about the population if the sample is very small.  Maybe knowing more about your data would help. $\qquad$

Comment: Possibly your data would constitute evidence against the correctness of the model. $\qquad$

Comment: @ Michael Hardy Population correlation coefficient can be expressed in some infinite series form and it only involves θ
. My sample size is only 30. Is any connection between sample correlation coefficient and estimates of parameter in general? R- software is giving whatever the value of estimated θ is correct or not ?